# How to access and edit local sqlite from Xamarin iOS app while debugging on device and not simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to access edit and update the local db sqlite of my mobile app while debugging. I was able to open using DB Browser for SQLite with the db path while running on simulator but not on actual iPhone. I can't debug on simulator anymore as I am using NFC library which fails to build on Simulators and builds only on devices.

Few of the solutions tried from existing answers:

- Tried opening the containers from Xcode -> Windows -> Devices and Simulators -> clicked on installed Apps to download containers. But it fails to show the db file present.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to edit a file on the device from outside the device while the app is running

Comment: @Jason Would it be possible to view the tables atleast?

Comment: You should be able to copy the app files from the device to your desktop and open them

Comment: You can try to refer to the answer in the thread ["How i do execute sqlite in iphone?"](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123497)